# syntax error in this mysql code

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

This is the mysql code written for ruby on rails application

```
Model.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM domainurls WHERE domaindetail_id = ?",@id ,"and count IN (SELECT Max( count ) FROM domainurls WHERE domaindetail_id =?",@id,")"])
```

It gives me error

```
"error is: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)"
```

Can anybody have idea what's wrong in the code?

Comment: May be you should add a space before "and count in..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you require data in two query because of IN can search data within an array.
Either your query

```
(SELECT Max( count ) FROM domainurls WHERE domaindetail_id =?",@id,")
```

will return many column.

So first execute this query and take counts in a array and after that execute second query.

I think you have understood.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `count` is a reserved word, so you have to escape it with `` like:

```
... and `count` IN (SELECT Max( `count` ) FROM domainurls ...
```